# Save content of table to a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem,
I want to create a variable wich is save the content of a table,
here is the code:

```html
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';
     $query = "SELECT transaksi.id as id, transaksi.deskripsi as deskripsi, 
       sum(case when shift='1' then transaksi.jumlah end) as shift1,
       sum(case when shift='2' then transaksi.jumlah end) as shift2,
       sum(transaksi.jumlah) as total
       from transaksi where tanggal='2014-11-15' group by id, deskripsi";
     $data1 = mysql_query($query) or die('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());
     $no=1;
     while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data1)){
     $output="
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>".$no++."</td>
       <td>".$row->id."</td>
       <td>".$row->deskripsi."</td>
       <td>".$row->shift1."</td>
       <td>".$row->shift2."</td>
       <td>".$row->total."</td>
      </tr>
     </table>";}
     echo $output;
     
?>
```

The code above show the result:

```
3   7100-04000  FINISH GOOD 32100-KVY-7000  20  11  31
```

The result show only last record of the query,

It should be like this:

```
1   7100-00000  FINISH GOOD 32100-KZRM-B200 10  9   19
2   7100-03000  FINISH GOOD 32100-KVB-N700  7   8   15
3   7100-04000  FINISH GOOD 32100-KVY-7000  20  11  31
```

Please help, because I want to use $output as $body in php mailer.

Thank you.

Comment: `$output = "";` in a loop just overwrites the variable, it doesn't append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data1)){
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$no++."</td>
            <td>".$row->id."</td>
            <td>".$row->deskripsi."</td>
            <td>".$row->shift1."</td>
            <td>".$row->shift2."</td>
            <td>".$row->total."</td>
        </tr>";}
echo "</table>";
```

or if you want to use a variable

```
$output = "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data1)){
        $output .= "<tr>
                <td>".$no++."</td>
                <td>".$row->id."</td>
                <td>".$row->deskripsi."</td>
                <td>".$row->shift1."</td>
                <td>".$row->shift2."</td>
                <td>".$row->total."</td>
            </tr>";}
$output .= "</table>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: it works, but how to save that result into variable so $body in my php mailer?

Comment: now I changed the 2nd code so it all will be in a variable

Comment: Wow.!
You are truly a savior,
what is the function of .=  sir?

Comment: It concatenates the new string with the previous one stored in the variable.

Comment: And that is what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$output = '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data1)){
$output .= "
    <tr>
        <td>".$no++."</td>
        <td>".$row->id."</td>
        <td>".$row->deskripsi."</td>
        <td>".$row->shift1."</td>
        <td>".$row->shift2."</td>
        <td>".$row->total."</td>
    </tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: it cannot work either. If you are inside the while loop the $output will be always regenerated.

Comment: I didnt add the while loop.. One could understand what to do so. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data1)){
 $output=?>

 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $no++;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->deskripsi;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->shift1;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->shift2;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->total;?></td>
 </tr>

<?php   
}
echo $output;
?>
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You are printing table for every row.